# how to suppress/remove ALL output from a cURL command (ruby)

Tags: ruby, curl, output, stdout, silent

I have:

```
info = `curl -s http://www.{insertwebsitehere}.com`
```

followed by some more arguments and I want to suppress everything that gets printed to the terminal. i know that `-s` got rid of the progress bar but I can't figure out how to completely remove ALL output of the cURL command.

This command gets run many times during the execution of the program and the output it produces messes everything up.

From what I understand there is no argument which removes it all and i have to redirect it, i just can't figure out how.

I've tried adding `> /dev/null/` to the end of it but it gave me errors

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: `info = \`curl -s http://www.{insertwebsitehere}.com\`` **does not** produce any output. What you probably see is the IRB/pry echoing `info`.

Comment: @mudasobwa ok so i mean anything that gets printed to the screen as a result of the cURL command above. so is there a way to remove that "irb/pry echoing" stuff. i dont want ANYTHING to come up after calling the command

Comment: You completely misunderstand what you are doing. Let me say this again: **this command does not produce any output**. To make sure, run it: `ruby -e 'info = \`curl -s http://www.google.com\`'`. If you do not want the console to echo your input, stop executing the command in console.

Comment: @mudasobwa yeah thats why in my most recent comment i didnt refer to it as output. im new to ruby so i most likely do misunderstand this. is there anywhere else (other than console) where i can execute that command from within my program?

Comment: I am unable to understand what do you want to do. I suggest you to go grab a book on Ruby, read it, do some exercises and after that turn back to curling an internet.

Comment: @mudasobwa i feel like im making it pretty clear what im trying to do. i am calling a curl command in backticks from within a program im writing. when i am executing the program in terminal with `ruby program.rb` it displays a bunch of curl lines when it gets to that curl line in backticks. you said that if i dont want the console to echo my input, then to stop executing the command in console. so where else can i execute it?

Comment: Please share more context, e. g. the whole program listing. **The line you introduced, `info = \`curl -s http://www.{insertwebsitehere}.com\`` does not print anything to the console**. I am not a fortuneteller; the code you showed does not behave as you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suppress stderr by adding `2>/dev/null`:

```
info = `curl -s http://www.{insertwebsitehere}.com 2>/dev/null`
```

but better way is to use some http library and fetch your page without starting additional process in a shell. For example there's `curb` - libcurl bindings for ruby

Comment: thanks heaps, this is EXACTLY what i needed. @mudasobwa take notes

Answer (score 0):

Remove `/` from the end of `/dev/null`

```
info = `curl -s http://www.{insertwebsitehere}.com > /dev/null`
```

But this will set `info` to empty string.
I think it is not what you want.